# How to calculate standard errors for GLMs fitted values "by-hand", without using predicted() in R?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, variance, standard-error, negative-binomial-distribution

I am running a negative binomial model without creating a glm object in R. I found an answer at StackExchange on how to get standard errors "by-hand" [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66946/how-are-the-standard-errors-computed-for-the-fitted-values-from-a-logistic-regre), but it shows only how to get values on a linear scale, not in the scale of the response, just as by default for type argument in predict(). To go from a linear scale to the scale of the fitted values for a negative binomial is just exp(fit), but how to get standard errors?

Answer (score 1):

To get the standard errors, you could either approximate them with the delta method, or just use simulation! You can probably use the `simulate()` generic in R.

For help on how to use the delta method, have a look at the answer to [Calculating the Variance using Delta Method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26916/calculating-the-variance-using-delta-method)

Following, an example on how to get the standard errors from the model object by simulation. I give an Poisson example, where we know the standard error from the mean, so as to be able to check on the simulations. Code:

```
set.seed(7*11*13)  
n  <-  100
N  <-  1000 # number of replications
y  <-  rpois(n, lambda=exp(5+x))
mod  <-  glm(y~x, family=poisson())
sims  <-  simulate(mod, nsim=N)  # this is sims from the estimated predictive distribution
preds  <-  matrix(0,n,N)
for (i in seq(along=sims)) {
    preds[,i]  <-  sims[[i]]
}
means  <-  apply(preds,1,mean)
vars   <-  apply(preds,1,var)
plot(means,vars)
```

the plot showing the expected linear relation.

Comment: thanks for your response, I agree using bootstrap or other randomization procedure as a valid alternative. To be honest your R code did not help me much, but generally this alternative looks like an easy solution I am going to try.

Comment: I will post an update with some better suggestions!