# Back transforming GLM standard errors

Tags: r, standard-error, back-transformation

This is a very simple question. When I back transform log transformed coefficients it usually looks like this:

```
exp(interceptvalue) + exp(paramter1 coefficicent)
```

When I want to back transform the standard errors. Do I do the same thing? Or do I just have to backtransform it like this:

```
exp(paramter1 std.e)
```

I guess my question comes down to: Are standard errors in a generalized linear model output (in R) additive like the coefficient estimates?

Comment: You cannot (at least not easily) backtransform standard errors, but you can backtransform confidence intervals. For an example see:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241970/how-to-calculate-standard-errors-for-glms-fitted-values-by-hand-without-using/243333#243333   and then adapt the methods used there.

Comment: You can approximate the standard error of a function of the maximum likelihood estimator using [the Delta Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method). Because coefficients in a GLM are typically estimated by maximum likelihood, this applies to your problem.

Comment: Can you explain the type of model you're fitting? I am having trouble thinking of typical cases where your "exp(interceptvalue) + exp(paramter1 coefficicent)" would be a sensible thing to do